# Function in C that for given binary (ordered) tree returns pointer to node that is the closest to the root and divisible by 3

Tags: c, binary-tree

Write function in C that for given binary (ordered) tree returns pointer to node that is the closest to the root and divisible by 3.

Here is what I have tried:

```
 Node* find_closest(Node* root) {
   if(root == NULL)
      return NULL;

   if(root->number % 3 == 0)
      return root;

   if(root->left != NULL)
      return find_closest(root->left);

   if(root->right != NULL)
      return find_closest(root->right);
   }
```

But this doesn't seem to be working. Can someone please help me with this problem?

Comment: In general, if you want something closest to the root, you should BFS. Your function is using DFS.

Comment: You need to try left and right, and then return the better result. The code you have will only check to the right if the left child of the root is NULL.

Comment: @user3386109 I see. Can you give me some hint what to change, how to "return better result", please. I am not sure.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Should I swap second "if" with third?

Comment: No, you have to work harder than simply 'swap second `if` with third'.  You need to find the level too.  If the left tree has an entry divisible by 3 at two levels down but the right tree has an entry one level down, you need to determine that the entry in the right tree is 'better' than the one in the left tree.  So you need to track the level where the node was found, somehow.  BFS (breadth-first search) would do that.  If both the left and right nodes are divisible by 3, which should be returned, or does that not matter?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler If there are two nodes divisible by 3 on same level, it doesn't matter which one should be returned, chose random one

Comment: Your code is actually searching for the leftmost node that is divisible by three not the topmost

Comment: What does it mean that the tree is *ordered*? Do you mean it is a binary *search* tree? Secondly, what does *closest* mean? Closest in *value*, or closest in *path* size?

Answer (score 1):

There are two basic ways to search a binary tree. DFS (depth-first search), and BFS (breadth-first search). DFS searches a tree by going as deep as it can in one direction, only going back up and trying other routes when it finds a dead-end. BFS searches the entire first layer of the tree, then the entire second layer of the tree and so on until it finds what it's looking for.

DFS is very easy to implement with recursion, and appears to be what you were trying to do with your code, but based on the problem you're trying to solve, BFS is a more appropriate algorithm to use, however it is a bit harder to implement because it involves a queue.

Here's an example implementation of BFS that should serve your purposes:

```
struct nodeQueue{ //This struct lets us store Node pointers in a queue
  Node *node;
  struct nodeQueue *next;
};

Node* find_closest(Node *root){
  if(!root)
    return NULL; //Just in case

  //Head and tail let us manage the queue of nodes that need to be searched next
  struct nodeQueue *head = malloc(sizeof(struct nodeQueue));
  struct nodeQueue *tail = head;
  *head = (struct nodeQueue){.node = root,.next = NULL}; //root is first in line

  while(head){ //As long as there are nodes to check
    Node *check = head->node; //Let's pull the next node out of the queue
    if(check->number % 3 == 0){  //It is divisible by three so we're done
      while(head){  //Free queue to prevent memory leak
        struct nodeQueue *hold = head->next;
        free(head);
        head = hold;
      }
      return check;  //return the node we found
    }
    //...otherwise
    //We need to add the left and right nodes to the queue so they can wait their turn
    if(check->left){ //If there is a node to the left put it at the end of the queue
      tail->next = malloc(sizeof(struct nodeQueue));
      tail = tail->next;
      *tail = (struct nodeQueue){.node = check->left,.next = NULL};
    }
    if(check->right){ //If there is a node to the right put it at the end of the queue
      tail->next = malloc(sizeof(struct nodeQueue));
      tail = tail->next;
      *tail = (struct nodeQueue){.node = check->right,.next = NULL};
    }
    struct nodeQueue *hold = head->next;
    free(head);
    head = hold; //Remove the node we just checked so the loop starts with the node next in line
  } //If this loop breaks it means none of the nodes' numbers are divisible by three
  return NULL;
}
```

Ensure `stdlib.h` is included for `malloc()` and `free()` and you must be using at least C99 for compound literals to work.

Answer (score 0):

Algorithmically, using a breadth-first search instead of a depth-first search is the most natural solution for finding the node closest to the root (in terms of depth in the tree) that meets a particular criterion.  That means testing all the nodes at each depth before testing any deeper nodes, which allows you to test the smallest number of nodes.  Read up on [breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) if you want to consider this.

Alternatively, you can do it with a depth-first search such as you are presently using, but to do so, you need to track and report back additional data.  Specifically, the depth at which the returned result was found, or an equivalent.  For example, consider this:

```
/*
 * Finds and returns one of the nodes among those whose number is evenly
 * divisible by three and that share a minimum distance from the specified
 * root, or returns null if the tree does not contain any nodes with numbers
 * divisible by three
 *
 * root: a pointer to the root node of the tree
 * result_depth: a pointer to a `size_t` wherein the depth of the result node
 *     should be written
 */
Node *find_closest_helper(Node *root, size_t *result_depth);
```

That can be implemented as a recursive depth-first search, with the `result_depth` argument used to pass the information between calls that is necessary to favor the nodes closer to the root.  The "`_helper`" part of the function name is meant to convey that you can preserve the function signature presented in the question by making that function a (non-recursive) wrapper around this one.